# Python 2.7.3 if compare a variable to a string

Tags: python, mysql-python, pyserial

```
import serial
import MySQLdb

dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","test","ISEF_DB") or die ("Could not connect to database")
cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = '/dev/ttyACM0'

try:
    print "Trying...",device
    arduino = serial.Serial(device, 250000)
except:
    print "Failed to connect on",device

try:
    data = arduino.readline() #read data
#   pieces = data.split("\t")
    print "The data is:",data
    if data == 461518B1:
        try:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '461518B1'")
            dbConn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print "data inserted"
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "Failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            print "done"
    elif data == 46154D41:
        try:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '46154D41'")
            dbConn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print "data inserted"
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "Failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            print "done"
    elif data == 4615A161:
        try:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '4615A161'")
            dbConn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print "data inserted"
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "Failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            print "done"
    elif data == 4616A511:
        try:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '4616A511'")
            dbConn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print "data inserted"
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "Failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            print "done"
    elif data == 46193031:
        try:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '46193031'")
            dbConn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print "data inserted"
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "Failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            print "done"
    elif data == 46196771:
        try:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '46196771'")
            dbConn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print "data inserted"
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "Failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            print "done"
    elif data == 461A79D1:
        try:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '461A79D1'")
            dbConn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print "data inserted"
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "Failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            print "done"
    elif data == 46211881:
        try:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '46211881'")
            dbConn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print "data inserted"
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "Failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            print "done"
    elif data == 465598F1:
        try:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '465598F1'")
            dbConn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print "data inserted"
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "Failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            print "done"
    elif data == 9A2DCDE4:
        try:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = '9A2DCDE4'")
            dbConn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            print "data inserted"
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "Failed to insert data"
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            print "done"
    else:
        print "Card not recognized"

except:
    print "Failed to get data"
```

This code is giving me the following error

```
  File "test.py", line 19
    if 461518B1 == data:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I am trying to do is compare a variable to a string, however it is not working. I can't see what I'm doing wrong. The data value can only be one of the 10 `if` statements which contain numbers and letters. I don't see any syntax problems. Could someone please help with the error?

Thank you

Comment: `461518B1` is not a string,`"461518B1"` or `'461518B1'` is.

Comment: Also, the trace you provide can't possible come from the code you've given, as `if 461518B1 == data:` doesn't exist in your code.

Comment: You are comparing something with something which it is not.

Answer (score -2):

While this does not directly answer your question (which was adequately addressed in the comments, *viz*,

> `461518B1` is not a string, `"461518B1"` or `'461518B1'`

(Use quotes to designate string literals)

I would point out that you can modify your code to avoid redundancy, since you appear to be using the same block of code in each of the if/elif` blocks:

```
id_values = ['461518B1', '46154D41', '4615A161', '4616A511', '46193031', '46196771', '461A79D1', '46211881', '465598F1', '9A2DCDE4']

data = arduino.readline() # read data
data = data.strip()       # get rid of whitespace like '\r\n'
print "The data is:",data
if data in id_values:
    try:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE 'ISEF_DB'.'attendance' SET 'present'='1' WHERE 'id' = '" + data + "'")
        dbConn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        print "data inserted"
    except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
        print "Failed to insert data"
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        print "done"
else:
    print "Card not recognized {}".format(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand.  The `id_values` are coming from a rfid card swiped to a arduino rfid evaluation shield.  The print line `The data is:` shows the correct **value** from the rfid card, however, the program ends with `Card not recognized`.  So, I know the card is being read, the value read IS one of the possible `id_values` required.  The variable `data` is not correlating to one of the `id_values` in the program, even though they match.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try `if data.strip() in id_values:`

Comment: @TurnerEison were you able to test the solution?

Comment: My problem was, the reader was reading it as the value then it was adding a \r\n to the end.

Comment: The `strip()` function *should* solve that, does it not?